# Folder on desktop as root

Tags: kubuntu

I have a folder at /media/TEST

I'm trying to make it available from the desktop using a folder widget.

The folder is owned by root and I cannot change the permissions for "other" from forbidden, neither from graphical interface nor from cmd line.

Anyone has a way to launch the folder widget as root maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a .desktop file to launch dolphin as root with gksu.

Content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TEST
Comment=Open TEST with root
Exec=gksu dolphin /media/TEST
Icon=file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;System;
```

If anyone finds a better way, feel free to answer and I will accept!

For example gksu requires the password every time, a way that doesn't need it would be appreciated.